# Left Join and remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have three tables, clients, job_allocations and jobs table. I want to select all clients that are not in a particular job, below are my tables.
**Clients table**

| id | Fullname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |
| 2 | Jane Doe |
| 3 | King James |
| 4 | Jere Gray |

**Jobs table**

| id | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Road Construction |
| 2 | Repair of Engines |

**job_allocations table**

| id | client_id | job_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 |

I want to select all clients that are not in **job_id=2**, but when I ran my query, I am getting **client id: 2 - Jane Doe** again, please how do I solve this?

I did this:

````
LEFT JOIN job_allocations ON job_allocations.client_id = clients.id
WHERE job_id <> 2 OR job_id IS NULL```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `NOT IN` clause as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT client_id 
                 FROM job_allocations 
                 WHERE job_id = 2)
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7xeJQSPQ9yPANoNaTYpUWy/0).

Answer (score 0):

So you will fetch all clients, but only jobs related to job_id <> 2

This query should work for you:

```
SELECT client.* 
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN job_allocations ON job_allocations.client_id = clients.id and job_id <> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **DISTINCT** keyword for selecting unique values